# Problem with duplicating rows and parsing values to a column in R

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table

I need to duplicate row in a data table and parse values to a column.

```
Table:     
St  Cty Name Crp  Plan Ins_ID  Yld_ID 
13  19  Ber  75   30   NA      NA    


22273028 21942993 22209124 22213153 22086558 22282068  

Output:
St  Cty Name Crp  Plan Ins_ID        Yld_ID 
13  19  Ber  75   30   22273028      NA
13  19  Ber  75   30   21942993      NA
13  19  Ber  75   30   22209124      NA
13  19  Ber  75   30   22213153      NA
13  19  Ber  75   30   22086558      NA
13  19  Ber  75   30   22282068      NA
```

How can I achieve this in R using `data.table`?

Comment: It that row a part of a data frame with more rows? Where is the list of Ins_ID located, is it a column in the dataframe or variable outside of it? Is it a vector of a character string you want to parse? All of these affect the solution.

Comment: The numeric values in the vector is coming from a different table. Yes, I have only one row in this in the Table. The number of rows to duplicate should be equal to the length of the numeric vector. In this case 6 rows since there are 6 numbers in the numeric vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this accomplish what you want?

```
dta <- structure(list(St = 13L, Cty = 19L, Name = "Ber", Crp = 75L, 
    Plan = 30L, Ins_ID = NA, Yld_ID = NA), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -1L))
dta <- data.table(dta)
Ins_ID <- c(22273028, 21942993, 22209124, 22213153, 22086558, 22282068)
dta.new <- data.table(dta[, 1:5], Ins_ID, Yld_ID=dta[, 7])
dta.new
#    St Cty Name Crp Plan   Ins_ID Yld_ID.Yld_ID
# 1: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22273028            NA
# 2: 13  19  Ber  75   30 21942993            NA
# 3: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22209124            NA
# 4: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22213153            NA
# 5: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22086558            NA
# 6: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22282068            NA
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer the data.table solution

Answer (score 0):

Within the given specifications, the problem becomes very easy.

```
ins_id_vector <- c(22273028, 21942993, 22209124, 22213153, 22086558, 22282068)  

expanded.table <- data.frame(
  St = Table$St,
  Cty = Table$Cty,
  Name = Table$Name,
  Crp = Table$Crp,
  Plan = Table$Plan,
  Ins_ID = ins_id_vector,
  Yld_ID = Table$Yld_ID
)
```

There is a thing in R called recycling. The data frame created above has all columnds (St, Cty, Name, Crp, Plan and Yld_ID containing only one value, whereas Ins_ID has many values, so the one value of those columns is used repeatedly to fill all the rows, making it easy.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer the data.table solution

Answer (score 0):

We can repeat the rows of the `data.table` based on the length of the vector and assign the vector to the column.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)
ins_id <- c(22273028,21942993,22209124,22213153,22086558,22282068)
dt <- dt[rep(1,length(ins_id)), ]
dt[, Ins_ID := ins_id]

dt
#   St Cty Name Crp Plan   Ins_ID Yld_ID
#1: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22273028     NA
#2: 13  19  Ber  75   30 21942993     NA
#3: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22209124     NA
#4: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22213153     NA
#5: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22086558     NA
#6: 13  19  Ber  75   30 22282068     NA
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(St = 13L, Cty = 19L, Name = structure(1L, .Label = "Ber", 
class = "factor"), Crp = 75L, Plan = 30L, Ins_ID = NA, Yld_ID = NA),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```